# gtk 3.0 use the same callback for several switches

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk3

I'm creating a Linux GUI using GTK3.0 and C and I want to use the same callback for several switches. In order to differentiate the switch that was clicked, I am trying to use the gpointer argument in g_signal_connect, but the callback doesn't seem to receive the right value.

I create the signals this way:

```
g_signal_connect(led1_switch, "state-set", G_CALLBACK(on_gpio_btn_click), (gpointer)"LED1");
g_signal_connect(led2_switch, "state-set", G_CALLBACK(on_gpio_btn_click), (gpointer)"LED2");
```

And the callback tries to get the gpointer passed:

```
    static void on_gpio_btn_click(GtkWidget *wid, gpointer ptr)
    {
        int gpio;
        int val = 0;
        char *gpio_switch = ptr;
...
```

But when I debug the application, the ptr pointer has the value 0x1, a wrong memory address.
[image]

Shouldn't it point to the memory address where the constant string "LED1" is stored?
what am I doing wrong? How can I share the same callback for several widgets? I have 8 switches to control GPIOs and I would prefer to have one callback for all of them instead of creating eight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature is wrong: the 2nd argument is the value of the switch's state, as can be found in the [documentation of the "state-set" signal](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/signal.Switch.state-set.html). That's also the reason why the value is `1`: that's the actual value of `TRUE`.

In other words, your callback will like this:

```c
    static void on_gpio_btn_click(GtkSwitch *swtch, gboolean state, gpointer ptr)
    {
        int gpio;
        int val = 0;
        char *gpio_switch = ptr;
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks nielsdg, it is working now. I'm new to gtk and I was assuming that the function signature was right since the compiler wasn't complaining, shouldn't the compilation fail if the function signature is not what it expects?

Comment: Note: with Gtkmm (C++ bindings for GTK), the compiler would have complained.